# Has anybody used MVCWizard.Wizard with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking to do a multistep webpage with around 5 steps, at least one of which will require a partial view with a grid and filtering.

I've downloaded the MVCWizard from NuGet, and set up my views, however I can find no example code for the controller.

Has anyone used this control? Do you have a sample controller I could see?

Alternatively, is there another wizard control which would do this?

Many Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. maybe too late for the answers, but I found it now!!! It can help anyone too, so in the nuget page of MVCWizard you can find the example.

[Nuget MVCWizard example](http://nuget.org/packages/MVCWizard.Web.Example)